# Environment Does Not Exist When Registering OpenAI Gym Environment

Tags: python, openai-gym

I am trying to register a custom gym environment on a remote server, but it is not working. I have been able to successfully register this environment on my personal computer using the Anaconda package manager framework, but have so far been unsuccesful without Anaconda (so I know the problem is not my environment). To try and work through this problem, I followed [this tutorial](https://towardsdatascience.com/beginners-guide-to-custom-environments-in-openai-s-gym-989371673952).

Here is my file structure:

```
gym-knot
│   setup.py  
│
└───gym_knot
    │   __init__.py
    │   
    └───envs
        │   __init__.py
        │   sliceenv.py
```

Where `gym-knot/setup.py` is

```
from setup tools import setup

setup(name='gym_knot', version='0.0.1', install_requires=['gym']
```

`gym-knot/gym_knot/__init__.py` is

```
from gym.envs.registration import register

register(
   id='Slice-v0',
   entry_point='gym_knot.envs:SliceEnv',
   max_episode_steps=300,
   reward_threshold=0,)
```

`gym-knot/gym_knot/envs/__init__.py` is

`from gym_knot.envs.sliceenv import SliceEnv`

I then ran `pip install --user -e gym-knot` to install it.

I have `import gym_knot` in the python file with my algorithm.

When I use the command `python3 knot_project.py` (which is the python file with my algorithm and whatnot), I get the error:

`gym.error.NameNotFound: Environment 'gym_knot:Slice' doesn't exist.`

I am really confused why I am getting this error because I followed the tutorial exactly and have also look at other resources that told me the same thing. Am I missing something? Could it be because my `knot_project.py` file is not in the `gym-knot` folder so it does not know that my environment exists? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This started happening to me after I upgraded gym from version 0.21 to 0.23, no solution yet but a good clue

[Update] It looks like it was a broken update

Download the zip file for 0.24.0 (or higher) for OpenAI from
https://github.com/openai/gym/releases and manually install this version with `pip install path/to/dir`

See `Re-added gym.make("MODULE:ENV") import style that was accidentally removed in v0.22 @arjun-kg` comment on patch notes